# Oracle Access Manager Causes Errors in Classic ASP Web Application

Tags: oracle, iis, asp-classic, oracle-access-manager

I am having an odd issue happening when utilizing Oracle Access Manager (OAM) on a Windows Server 2012 SR2 when using it in combination with Classic ASP.

I have used the exact same code (classic ASP) on the same server, just disabling OAM, and everything works fine (regardless if the AppPool is set for the default of 64bit or if I change it to enable 32bit).

However, with OAM enabled, as soon as I hit a page on my Classic ASP code that retrieves data from an Oracle database, I get the following error in the Events:

> The description for Event ID 2 from source Oracle.OCI.DLL cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
>   If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.
>   The following information was included with the event:
>   **OraPlc11.Dll** cannot be loaded.
>   OS Error message: The specified procedure could not be found.

Again, when not using OAM - the page returns the expected data with no errors.

I have tried to configure my Application Pool to allow 32bit, or use it in default of 64bit - but this did not help.

I am still guessing it is a 32bit vs 64bit issue - however, cannot see why the site would work fine as long as OAM is not enabled.

Comment: Relevant? [Why does Oracle not find oci.dll?](//stackoverflow.com/q/30568594)

Comment: Lankymart - not sure. Works fine when OAM is disabled. The AppPool crashes once a page requesting data from Oracle is requested when OAM is enabled. The result is the error above.